# Ruby: Am I using the 'do block' incorrectly? I'm getting "undefined method `scan' for #<Hash:>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to display unique IPS alerts for my dashboard. If I display `@filtered_snort_detail_query` I get loads of alerts, and many could be ignored since alerts are packet based and one attack can generate 100's or 1000's of alerts. No need to display all of them. I'm trying to use `scan` to find the sig ID, source IP, and destination IP.

When it's all said and done, I'm looking to display `@snort_dash_info` in my view vs. `@filtered_snort_detail_query`

My error:

```
undefined method `scan' for #<Hash:0x007f088a7a4830>

app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:139:in `block in index'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:138:in `each'
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:138:in `index'
```

Code from the controller (Line 139 starts with `sid_data`):

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      @filtered_snort_detail_query = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.push(ips_detail)
      end
      if @filtered_snort_detail_query.count > 0
        @snort_dash_info = Array.new
        sid = Array.new
        ip_src = Array.new
        ip_dst = Array.new
        @filtered_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_alerts|
          sid_data = ips_alerts.scan(/\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]/)
          src_ip_data = ips_alerts.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          dst_ip_data = ips_alerts.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          sid.push(sid_data[0]) unless sid_data[0].nil?
          ip_src.push(src_ip_data[0]) unless src_ip_data[0].nil?
          ip_dst.push(dst_ip_data[1]) unless dst_ip_data[1].nil?
          snort_details = [{:ips_info => sid},{:ips_info => ip_src}, {:ips_info => ip_dst}]
          snort_details_info = snort_details.uniq do |show_me|
            show_me[:ips_info]
            end
          @snort_dash_info.push(snort_details_info)
          end
        end
    end
```

Comment: What is your `@filtered_snort_details_query`? How do you set it? It seems it's an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it some what working, so I guess this question should be done. I'm not getting the undefined method for scan anymore, and I've verified that my `unique_ids` are working. The only issue is I'm now displaying the `unique_ids` and not using them to remove duplicate alerts. That's for another question I guess..

`Code:`

```
    if @es_snort_detail_query.count > 0
      sid = Array.new
      ip_src = Array.new
      ip_dst = Array.new
      @snort_dash_info = Array.new
      @es_snort_detail_query.each do |ips_detail|
        next if ips_detail['_source']['type'] != 'snort-ips'
        next if ips_detail['_source']['@timestamp'] < @ts
        if ips_detail['_source']['message'].nil?
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        else
          text_msg = ips_detail['_source']['message']
        end
        unless text_msg.nil?
          sid_data = text_msg.scan(/\[\d+:\d+:\d+\]/)
          src_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
          dst_ip_data = text_msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)

          sid.push(sid_data[0]) unless sid_data[0].nil?
          ip_src.push(src_ip_data[0]) unless src_ip_data[0].nil?
          ip_dst.push(dst_ip_data[1]) unless dst_ip_data[1].nil?

          unique_ids = [{:ips_info => sid},{:ips_info => ip_src}, {:ips_info => ip_dst}]

          snort_details_info = unique_ids.uniq do |show_me|
            show_me[:ips_info]
            end
          @snort_dash_info.push(snort_details_info)
          end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each_pair` like:

```
ips_alerts.each_pair { |k, v| puts "#{k} #{v}" }
```

So in order to get what you want, try:

```
ips_alerts.each_pair do |k, v|
  if k == "sid_data" # pure assumption on my part
    sid_data = v.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
  end
end
```

Sorry I can't think of a prettier way but it works.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, thanks. I'm new to ror dev so it may take me a min. or two...